# Need help to understand why request. getParameter is returning null

Tags: javascript, jsp

The request.getParameter is returning null. But I see the value is captured by document.getElementById but not by request.getParameter. Dont know why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

           function checkExists(){

             var NUSN=document.getElementById('UName').value;
                       //  alert("helloeeee ");
                      // alert (" NUSN is : " + NUSN);
            <% 
            Connection conn = null;
            String url= "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Movie";
            String driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
            String username ="sam";
            Class.forName(driver);           
            conn=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,"sa");
            String NUSN1 = request.getParameter("UName");
            System.out.println("New user is : ");
            System.out.println(NUSN1);   //here the value is null- dont know why
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select username from Userdetails where usename in ("+ NUSN1+")");
            while (rs.next()){
                if (rs.first()){
                    out.println("User name already taken");

                }
                else out.println("User name Valid");
            }



            %>
}
</script>
```

Here is my form: posting just the relevant part

```
    <tr> <td><label for="User Name">USER NAME:</label></td><br><br>
    <td><input type="text" name="UName" value="" size="10" id="UName" /></td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: <td><label for="User Name">USER NAME:</label></td><br><br>
  <td><input type="text" name="UName" value="" size="10" id="UName" />

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are returning false on your form submission, that's why is null!
See my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
    if (request.getParameter("code") != null)   
        System.out.println(" AFTER SUBMIT code: "+request.getParameter("code"));
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
Code:<input type="text" name="code" id="code"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
function validateForm(){
    console.log(document.querySelector("#code"));

    <%
        System.out.println("CODE: "+request.getParameter("code"));
    %>
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your reply. I should have been more clear. my apologies. The checkExists () function is an onblur event created on the input box. Iam writing it to check if the username is unique or not.

Comment: I know why request.getParameter is returning null value. its because  JSP is a server-side scripting language, it will not be able to "see" what the user is selecting from the field unless the value is submitted to the server somehow for processing, such as a form submission.(this i found on web) and onblur event does not submit form. hence the null value.